# Require construct Behaviour in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, nodejs-stream

I am learning node js and I am at the sterams module.

I have below query - What is the difference between these two statements.

```
const {Readable} = require("stream") 
and 
const  Readable  = require("stream")
```

Below Code Snippet works . Means data is emitted by Read Stream and end of stream is also raised.

But when `const {Readable}` is converted to `const Readable` , it stops working

Can anybody help why this behaviour ?

```
const {Readable} = require("stream"); // changing const Readable = require("stream") doesn't work 

const createReadStream = () => {

    const data = ["one","two","three"];

    return new Readable({

        read(){
            if (data.length === 0) {
                console.log('data ended');
                this.push(null);
            } else{
                console.log('reading data');
                this.push(data.shift());
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two:

```
const {Readable} = require("stream"); 

const  Readable  = require("stream");
```

Are not the same and the second will clearly not work.  The second assigned the whole module handle to `Readable` whereas the first assigns the `.Readable` property in the module to your variable `Readable`.  Perhaps what you meant to compare is these two:

```
const {Readable} = require("stream"); 

const Readable = require("stream").Readable;
```

These two are pretty much equivalent.  The `const {Readable}` syntax is called destructuring and is a shortcut for the syntax in the second line.

---

Note, the destructuring syntax really shows its advantages when you are fetching multiple properties at once:

```
const {Readable, Writable, Transform, pipeline} = require("stream");
```

As this declares and initializes multiple variables in one line of code.